# How we got $e^{-λ}$ from the $\sum_{j=0}^∞{\frac{λ^j}{j!}}$

Tags: calculus

It might be stupid question, but I cannot understand how we got $e^λ$ from the below expression (it is taken from Poisson distribution proof):
$$\sum_{j=0}^∞{\frac{λ^j}{j!}} = e^λ$$

The only thing that confuses me - how did we get rid of $j$ power? That would make sense for me if we would not have λ raised into $j$ power...

I know that 
$$\sum_{j=0}^∞{\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}} = e^{-1}$$

but it made a sense for me because -1 in any power can be either -1 or 1... but in the first expression with the raise of exponent our λ will be changing in its size significantly. I might be dump.. but yeah, this tricks me.. Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you ever heard of Taylor series?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Taylor series for $e^x$ is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} + \dotsb$$
and $e^x$ is equal to this series for all values of $x$.
Now plug in $\lambda$!

Comment: That exclamation looks like a factorial. =P

Answer (score 2):

From Walter Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis" page 1.

"This is the most important function in mathematics.  It is defined, for every complex number $z$, by the formula
$$\exp(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{z^n}{n!}}."$$